# Как реализовать функцию комбинирования слова для создания ключа на вход хешфункции(для хеш таблицы)

Tags: c, алгоритм, хеширование

Есть задание

> Разработать функцию на языке программирования Си. Функция должна
>   выполнять комбинирование (сжатие) слов ключа поиска. Принимать на вход
>   поисковую строку символов (ключ поиска) и возвращающий сжатый ключ,
>   позволяющий использовать его для вычисления хеш-функции.

Я написал вот такую функцию

```
unsigned short WordCombination(const char* str){
    unsigned short lenght = strlen(str);
    unsigned short modSum = 0;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < lenght; i+=2){
        unsigned short word = str[i]; //размещение символа в шестнадцатибитной сетке
        word = (word << BYTE) | str[i + 1]; //объеденение двух симвлов
        word = (word >> STEP) | (word << (WORDSIZE - STEP)); //циклический сдвиг
        modSum += word; //накопление суммы по мо
    }
    return modSum;
}
```

Но на тесте с переставлением байтов в строке она дает коллизии. Пробовал делать кучу арифметических действий с правым и левом байтом в объединении, но все равно хотябы одна коллизия в строке из 3 байт получается.
Как можно модернизировать эту функцию, чтоб убрать коллизии на таких простых тестах.

Comment: При отображении всех возможных вариантов 3-х байт (2^24 значений) в 2 байта (unsigned short 2^16 значений) колиизии всегда будут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avp дело говорит. Должно быть что-то, что ограничивает диапазон входных значений, и тем самым позволит сжимать без потерь. Например, должен быть ограничен алфавит входных значений вроде только латиницы в нижнем регистре. Тогда строку из 3 символов получится без потерь запихнуть в 2 байта, т.к в латинице лишь 25 символов, на это надо 5 бит, а в двух байтах 16 бит.

Получается так:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Ограниченный алфавит
const unsigned VALUE_MIN = 'a';
const unsigned VALUE_MAX = 'z';
// Сколько бит на него надо
const unsigned VALUE_BITS = 5;
// Сколько байт удастся сжать без потерь
// VALUE_BITS / два байта = 5/16
const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 3;

unsigned short WordCombination(const char* str) {
    unsigned length = strlen(str);
    unsigned short result = 0;
    if (length > MAX_LENGTH) {
        printf("- got too long string of %u", length);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        unsigned char v = str[i];
        // Проверка границ
        if (v < VALUE_MIN) {
            printf("- got too small byte %u", v);
            v = VALUE_MIN;
        }
        if (v > VALUE_MAX) {
            printf("- got too large byte %u", v);
            v = VALUE_MAX;
        }
        // Добавление со смещением
        unsigned short add = (str[i] - VALUE_MIN) << (i * VALUE_BITS);
        result |= add;
        // printf("- add %u\n", add);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const char* s = "blh";
    unsigned short v = WordCombination(s);
    printf("Source: %s\nResult: %u\n", s, v);
}
```